# Flutter initState TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starting to use Flutter and i found these 2 ways to initialize a controller to use it in a TextField but, what's the difference between use one of other?

Here's the first:

```
TextEditingController _controller;

@override
  void initState() {
_controller = TextEditingController();
super.initState();
}

...
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
),
```

And this the other way:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
...
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
),
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In case of the TextEditingController you can directly declare it like the second way you're doing it here, because it always depends how a Class has to be declared. TextEditingController is more convenient and you can do that :). Regarding initState: These are Widget-Lifecycle methods which are shiped with StatefulWidgets only. In StatelessWidgets you wouldn't have these methods.

Comment: Interesting, I have to learn some things like the Widget-Lifecycle methods, I appreciate it man!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the initState() method is called in StatefullWidget when it is instanciated for the first time it have the same effect that when you inicialice  in a constructor. In conclution there´s not any parctical difference except that you can´t inicialice a variable with initState() in a StatelessWidget

Comment: So I can use any way to use a controller considering that the widget is Stateful, that's I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that using `final` assures you at *compile time* that the `controller` variable will always point to the same object (i.e. its value will never change).

Answer (score 0):

**Initlize TextEditingController The Right:**

```
late final TextEditingController _controller;

@override
  void initState() {
 super.initState();
_controller = TextEditingController();
}

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose;
    super.dispose();
  }

...
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
),
```